# iPhoto does not recognise the photos on the SD card of my new camera.

Tags: photos, photos.app, sd-card

I am running Lion on iMac and iPhoto is up to date.  my new camera is a sony a6000.  The photos show up in the import window, even with an image of the camera, but when I ask iPhoto to import them it comes up with a message saying Unreadable Files - file is in unrecognised format. The photos are RAW but I've never had a  problem importing RAW files before. This is what the file is displaying as in the unreadable files window.
/Users/SueHewett/Pictures/iPhoto Library/Import/Masters/Roll 1/_DSC2044.ARW

Comment: Does the same thing occur in Image Capture? It is a separate app located in ~/Applications/Utilities/

Comment: Image Capture won't import them to iPhoto - it tries to, but iPhoto then has the same message.  Image Capture will import them to Pictures in Finder, but they're not much use to me there.  I think I need to upgrade the OS X.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Apple's RAW format support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201071), Sony Alpha ILCE-6000 support was added in [Digital Camera RAW Compatibility Update 5.06](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1765?locale=en_US) released in August 2014.  This update requires a minimum of OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.5 with iPhoto version 9.4.3 or later.

I recommend upgrading to the latest OS X version supported by your Mac.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at upgrading - have been a bit reluctant to do that so far.